# How to pass Rc<RefCell<dyn T>> to fn that wants &dyn T?

Tags: rust, dereference, trait-objects, interior-mutability

I have trouble passing an argument to a fn.

```
trait T {}

struct S {
    others: Vec<Rc<RefCell<dyn T>>>
}

impl S {
    fn bar(&self) {
        for o in self.others {
            foo(&o.borrow());
        }
    }
}

fn foo(t: &dyn T) {}
```

The compiler tells me:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::cell::Ref<'_, (dyn T + 'static)>: T` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:14:17
   |
14 |             foo(&o.borrow());
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `T` is not implemented for `std::cell::Ref<'_, (dyn T + 'static)>`
   |
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn T`
```

I thought this was like in the [example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html#having-multiple-owners-of-mutable-data-by-combining-rct-and-refcellt) in the rust book, where the `Rc` is auto dereferenced and to get the value out of the RefCell I could call `borrow()`.

I tried explicit dereferencing too, but nothing seems to work.

How can I call `foo()` for each `dyn T` object in `self`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error says, `Ref<X>` does not automatically implement every trait that `X` implements. For a type to be coerced to a trait object, it needs to  implement that trait.

You can explicitly dereference the `Ref` and then borrow it again:

```
impl S {
    fn bar(&self) {
        for o in &self.others {
            foo(&*o.borrow());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use this, I get a similar compiler error, saying Borrow is not implemented for Rc<Refcell>.

Comment: I don't understand why (in the original question) the compiler complained about the borrow() call. I mean RefCell does have a borrow method, even though it does not implement the Borrow trait. Why is the RefCell not auto dereferenced out of the Rc so I can call borrow on the RefCell?

Comment: Yet, the solution works on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=dcc273be130b8613f3729127f4cab369)

Comment: Ah I had Borrow in use, that's why duuhh!

Comment: @David If you do need `Borrow` as well, you can use the `RefCell` one explicitly: `foo(&*RefCell::borrow(&o))`